# How do I connect to a remote MySQL database through an android device?

Tags: android, mysql, http

```
    public static final String URL="jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2/mydatabase";
    public static final String USER="root";
    public static final String PASSWORD="apple";
    public static final String Driver_Class="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
```

The above URL works fine when i connect to it locally... My question is what change do I make in order to have a remote access through a device??? (Its to do with "http" but how do i write it,the URL?)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure root is configured to be able to login remotely. [Quick tutorial](http://benrobb.com/2007/01/15/howto-remote-root-access-to-mysql/) 
Also make sure 3306 tcp port for MySQL server is open.

I've used this [tutorial](http://appinventor.blogspot.ca/2011/07/android-mysql.html) in past, give it a try.